# Conversion of array of object to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects:

```
const action_triggers = [
  {
    onClick: {
      action_id: "1",
    },
  },
  {
    onLoad: {
      action_id: "2",
    },
  },
];
```

How do I convert it into the following by JavaScript?

```
const action_trigger = {
  onClick: {
    action_id: 1
  },
  onLoad: {
    action_id: 2
  }
}
```

Comment: What should happen if you have two objects with the onClick key? You can't have duplicate keys in an object.

Comment: The key question to ask is: how helpful would this question and answers be to future visitors of the site?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the reduce version

```
const _l = (s) => {
    console.log(s);
};
let flatter = action_triggers.reduce((propogator, prop) => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(prop)) {
        propogator[key] = value;
    }
    return propogator;
}, {});
_l(flatter);
```

Helps with conditionally doing whatever you want to {} the input